# Why did formatting win 7 computers to windows 10 double their cpu-z bench score?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cpu, cpu-z

So I work at a company as an IT guy while I am doing my computer engineering degree. Doing hardware and software maintenance of computers is part of my job. I have had a weird experience with two of the computers. These two computers(one desktop one laptop) were the slowest computers in the company. The laptop is Dell Inspiron N5010 with i3 370M(2 cores, 4 threads) processor. The desktop is HP 500B MT with E5800(2 cores 2 threads) processor.

At first, both of these computers had windows 7 running on them. CPU-Z(1.87.0) benchmark of the desktop was 113(single thread), 227(multithread). The laptop was 82, 267.

After I formatted these computers with windows 10 and ran the same CPU-Z version benchmark, **I got exactly double performance with both computers. Both single threading and multithreading scores got doubled.**

After formatting with windows 10, desktop got 270, 510. Laptop got 180, 520.

What is causing this? Physical core number stayed the same. Logical core number stayed the same. I am baffled.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Did you do the benchmark in the exact same conditions? I mean, a newly formatted PC is always better than with all those programs running. I don't see much of a point on this question but..

Comment: By format them with Windows 10, do you mean completely reformatted the hard drive and started with a clean slate? Or did you just upgrade the OS and leave the programs/files all the same?

Comment: @DrZoo Completely reformatted the hard drive.

Comment: @TiagoCaldeira Before formatting the desktop computer to windows 10, i formatted that same desktop to windows 7(because it had problems). And i didnt see the cpu benchmark change. When i formatted again with windows 10 i saw the cpu benchmark score double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you upgraded from 32 bit Windows 7 to 64 bit Windows 10? According to [this FAQ](https://www.cpuid.com/news/51-cpu-z-1-79-new-benchmark-new-scores.html) under the point **What algorithm does the benchmark use...** they state that

> the 32-bit version keeps using the legacy x87 instructions, resulting
>   in almost half of the x64 performance

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps your Windows 10 image has a better driver selection than the Windows 7 install source you used.

Also, were all installs fully patched?

Update: The only real way to tell now would be to do a clean install from Windows 7 installation media (i.e. a DVD or USB), make sure its fully updated and run again.  Otherwise perhaps be happy you now have better performance :)

Comment: I downloaded windows 10 home from website of windows. When it comes to windows 7, i used settings->Update & Security->Reset this PC

Comment: "Reset this PC" may have set it back with an image before various service packs and updates (interestingly I thought that was the the terminology post-windows 7 but hey-ho)

Comment: Windows 7 does not have a "Reset this PC" feature.